# Вызов определенного действия мессенджера

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Заинтересовался разработкой приложений на андроид и решил начать с чего-нибудь простого, например *Приложение для обработки контактов в телефоне*.
При анализе информации из таблицы Data (`ContactsContract.Data`), обнаружил записи, созданные мессенджерами (в частности, WhatsApp). Многие приложения, предназначенные для просмотра отдельных контактов в телефоне, позволяют выполнить определенные действия с контактом, если у него есть данные мессенджера (опять пример с WhatsApp - *выйти на аудиозвонок*, *написать пользователю*, *сделать видеозвонок*).

Как реализовать эту функцию?

Я примерно понимаю, что надо использовать *Intent*, но пока не представляю, какое именно действие использовать (Intent Action) и как мне передать приложению нужную функцию (в таблице Data функция представлена в столбце mimetype).

Правка 1:
Уточню: я получаю из таблицы *ContactsContract.Data* следующую информацию:

1. ```
   MIMETYPE: vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call
   ACCOUNT_TYPE: com.whatsapp
   DATA1: 77777777777@s.whatsapp.net
   DATA2: WhatsApp
   DATA3: Аудиозвонок +7 777 777-77-77`
   ```
2. ```
   MIMETYPE: vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.profile
   ACCOUNT_TYPE: com.whatsapp
   DATA1: 77777777777@s.whatsapp.net
   DATA2: WhatsApp
   DATA3: Написать +7 777 777-77-77`
   ```
3. ```
   MIMETYPE: vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.video.call
   ACCOUNT_TYPE: com.whatsapp
   DATA1: 77777777777@s.whatsapp.net
   DATA2: WhatsApp
   DATA3: Видеозвонок +7 777 777-77-77`
   ```

Из первой части требуется начать аудиовызов, из второй - выйти в диалог с пользователем, а из третьей - начать видеозвонок

Comment: Если вы хотите вызвать WhatsApp из своего приложения, то делайте по официальной инструкции : https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012

Comment: @ДамирАрманов, как я понял, в данной инструкции объясняется "как открыть WhatsApp с готовым текстом в сообщении и выбрать нужного получателя". В моем случае требуется выполнить нужное действие с заранее известным контактом.

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить действие в приложении, которое "умеет" и посмотреть в LogCat. Возможно не на всех устройствах,  intent'ы выводятся в лог (кроме экстра данных)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом проб и ошибок смог таки добиться желаемого результата (вызов определенного действия мессенджера), код решения:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, "Значение _ID в строки из таблицы DATA");
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(uri, "MIMETYPE строки из таблицы DATA");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Открыть диалог с пользователем Вы сможете так:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "+79*********");
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

На `Intent.ACTION_CALL` Whatsapp не реагирует и не предоставляет никакого API для разработчиков. В интернете есть библиотеки, ковыряющие что-то через интроспекцию, но ничего дельного я не нашел. Может, у кого то еще есть опыт в этом вопросе.